# findFragmentById returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I have an activity with a navigation drawer and empty layout. On create of the activity, I display the fragment(in the empty layout of the activity). The fragment's id is `dateVehicleMainContent`. On selecting the navigation items I display other fragments. When back is pressed it returns to the previous fragment.

I want to display a logout dialog when the current fragment is the first fragment I displayed(`dateVehicleMainContent`). It is displayed when back is pressed for every fragment. I don't want it to be displayed in other fragments which occupy the empty layout of the activity. So I use `findFragmentById`. MAybe this is not working because I display the fragment in the empty layout of the `Activity`.

DateTimePicker is the fragment class.

This is the `Activity` with the empty layout and with the `onBackPressed()` to check if current fragment is the fragment with id `dateVehicleMainContent`

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.dateVehicleMainContent);

    if (currentFragment instanceof DateTimePicker) {


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DateVehiclePicker.this);

        alertDialog.setTitle("Logout");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to Logout?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                sessionManager.logoutUser();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivity(intent);
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });alertDialog.show();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

The Activity's layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.prematixsofs.taxiapp.DateVehiclePicker">
<!-- The main content view -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <!-- Profile Box -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#ff02c7c4"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/user" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/viewProfile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="View Profile"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the part of the fragment's layout ..when this fragment is displayed I want to show alert dialog for logout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dateVehicleMainContent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.looper.loop.DateTimePicker">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/dateVehicleLinearLayoutMainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Try using `findFragmentByTag()` instead and make sure all your Fragments have tags :) Furthermore, notify your parent Activity with a callback from `YourFragment.onDetach()` to display the dialog.

Comment: @Shark Hi..I'm new to android. Can you provide me a link with an example or answer with an example?

Comment: I pasted some of the code I had nearby to illustrate the approach.

Answer (score 0):

OK, lemme try something like this. This isn't a very complete example, nor it's buildable because it uses some of my custom code (classes) but it demonstrates the approach very well.

```
String title = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
tag = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_FRAGMENT_TAG);
FilterFragment currentFragment = null;

        if (tag.equals(FragmentMyWishlist.TAG)) {
            currentFragment = (FilterFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentMyWishlist.TAG);
        } else if (tag.equals(FragmentMyLibrary.TAG)) {
            currentFragment = (FilterFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentMyLibrary.TAG);
        }
```

You may not have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` and can get the job done with `getFragmentManager()` but the idea is the same. I had to use SupportFragmentManager because I'm using `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

EDIT:

`FragmentMyWishlist` has a `public static String TAG = "FragmentMyWishlist";`
`FragmentMyLibrary` has a `public static String TAG = "FragmentMyLibrary";`

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid. What's `FragmentMyWishlist.TAG`. Is it the tag you set when replacing the fragment like this: `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.mainContent, new DateTimePicker(),"tags").commit();`? I tried to check with a string containing `tags` like you did with `MyFragment.TAG`, but TAG cannot resolve. Am I doing it right?

Comment: where do you set the StringExtra? what is the value of `tag`.

Comment: it is set in the activity that raises this activity, which changes these fragments... the value of `tag` is fetched from the `Intent` that started the activity, and then the activity knows to which `Fragment` the date is being routed.